# C doesn't run in VS Code

Tags: c

When I try to run c in vs code this shows up in terminal:

`cd "c:\Users\numb1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\C Files\" && gcc main.c -o main && "c:\Users\numb1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\C Files\"main bash: cd: too many arguments`

The problem with this is that somehow *main* is after the quotes. How do I fix this?

Maybe I should configure tasks.json somehow?

Comment: Avoid using spaces in your path. Put your files on `C:\c_Projects\Project1` ...

Comment: The issue is that "main" is included within the quotes, causing it to be treated as part of the path instead of a separate command... Try `cd "c:\Users\numb1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\C Files\" && gcc main.c -o main && ./main
`

Comment: which shell are you using? It looks like you're using bash in VS Code so the last backslash escaped the closing quote

Comment: Also do not use russian letters in programming.

Comment: @gulpr That is so random. Most programming languages are Unicode-compatible now, there is nothing wrong with "using russian letters in programming". How else would they print out a text message their users could read? But even more, there is no evidence in the OP's post that they are "using russian letters in programming". The only "russian letters" I see are `Рабочий стол`, which is a name of a directory created by Windows. It means "Desktop". I happen to have `デスクトップ` in its place, simply by having purchased my PC in Japan.

Comment: @Amadan and? Better to avoid

Comment: @gulpr The times are gone were US-ASCII-only names for paths and filenames are required, even more just letters and digits. The few remaining places are some M$ leftovers and hobbyists' programs. As we can see, VS Code is none of them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bash instead of the expected cmd.exe of Windows.

Bash interprets characters differently than cmd, so the backslash `\` escapes the trailing quotation mark `"` and makes it a part of the argument instead of the end marker.

You have two options:

- Use cmd.
- Change the configuration of VS Code to use bash to build.

---

*Disclaimer*

I tried to find information and resources for the second option. But my impression that VS Code is little more than an editor in its infancy was verified, again. It still has a long way to become a serious IDE. This is one reason why I don't use it. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed my default terminal to cmd and it worked. Do you know how can I configure my bash terminal?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using "tasks.json" in Visual Studio Code, you can create a task that encapsulates these commands. Try like this in ".json" configuration:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "buildCProgram",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
        "main.c",
        "-o",
        "main"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Try this configuration to run C code.

Comment: That command line already looks like it was automatically created by VS Code. Also, without identifying which part is wrong, how would your answer solve the issue?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you put double Andpersands at the end. Maybe removing those will fix it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).